# FloatingActionButton in Activity with multiple Fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, nullpointerexception, floating-action-button

I have an issue that I can't seem to solve.

I have an activity with a list fragment (landscape and portrait) and an addItem fragment.

There is a FloatingActionButton on the Activity, but I can't seem to figure out how to set up its onClickListener.

The getViewById always returns null so the setOnClickListener has no object to call from. Why is this and how do I fix it?

Am I doing multiple fragments wrong and this is my problem?

Note: I left out the landscape fragment/layout for brevity's sake. It's the same as the portrait with a different id.

MainActivity.java

```
package tlw.app;

import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<String> activeFragments = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_list);

        FragmentManager fManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fTrans = fManager.beginTransaction();
        Configuration configInfo = getResources().getConfiguration();

        activeFragments.clear();
        if(configInfo.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
            ListFragmentLand fragmentListLand = new ListFragmentLand();
            fTrans.replace(R.id.main_container, fragmentListLand);

            activeFragments.add("list_land");
        } else {
            ListFragment fragmentListPort = new ListFragment();
            fTrans.replace(R.id.main_container, fragmentListPort);
            activeFragments.add("list_port");
        }
        fTrans.commit();

        if (activeFragments.contains("list_port") || activeFragments.contains("list_land")){
            FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
            fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    FragmentManager fManager = getFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction fTrans = fManager.beginTransaction();

                    activeFragments.clear();
                    ItemAddFragment fragmentAdd = new ItemAddFragment();
                    fTrans.replace(R.id.main_container, fragmentAdd);
                    activeFragments.add("add");
                    fTrans.commit();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

ListFragment.xml

```
package tlw.app;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class ListFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);
    }
}
```

fragment_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="tlw.app.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="List Portrait"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

ItemAddFragment.java

```
package tlw.app;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class ItemAddFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add, container, false);
    }
}
```

fragment_add.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_add"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Name:"
            />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editText_name"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I suggest creating a new Android Studio project and build up a simple example of what you want to do. Create a single activity with a single fragment and a FAB. Add an OnClickListener to the FAB. Can you get that much to work correctly?

Comment: In your actual app, it appears that you have two different layouts: one with a FAB and another without. You can simplify your code greatly by creating two different activities. This will avoid all the convoluted if statements.

Comment: You should also use different `layout-*` folders rather than Java code to support different screen orientations.

Comment: I have built a project with a FAB before and got it to work fine.

The main activity layout contains the FAB. I would like it to be on all of the fragments so I thought this would be the best place to put it.

Comment: What is the purpose of `if (activeFragments.contains("list_port") || activeFragments.contains("list_land")){`?

Comment: From what I can tell, this `if` statement adds the OnClickListener to the FAB which will launch the "add" fragment. Does the "add" fragment also need the FAB?

Comment: Can you share the error logs..?? so can find the expected errors..

Comment: No, the add fragment did not need the FAB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
setContentView(R.layout.fragment_list);
```

This sets the layout used for your activity which does not have a FAB. Change this line to

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

In general, whenever `findViewById()` returns `null`, you need to be sure that the correct XML is loaded and that it contains the `id` you are trying to find.

Comment: This fixed the issue! I still have some issues with the fragments not showing the way I want, but I think I can figure those out. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Please change this portion of the code in the `MainActivity`

**FROM**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_list);
```

**TO**

```
 @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Mistakes::

--Passing wrong xml instance::

--Trying to fetch the toolbar before the xml was actually set..

Please tell if more assistance needed